# Python : Find things in a list

Tags: python, list

I’m building a script which I’m using to deploy applications on certain virtual machines.
I’m using a list like this to configure some settings :

```
myList = [["APP1", "X", "v3", "AAA", "2"],
            ["APP2", "X", "v3", "AAA", "2"],
            ["APP3", "Z", "v3", "BBB", "2"],
            ["APP4", "Z", "v3", "BBB, "2"],
            ["APP5", "Z", "v3", "AAA", "2"]]
```

And I have a list which contains all virtual machines that are usable to deploy these applications on.

```
vmList = [[“AAA_hostname”, “BBB_hostname”]] etc.
```

How can I loop through the first list “myList”, and find the entry where the first 3 characters are the same in “vmList”? Please note, it may be that the last line has a value like the first. (See the AAA on the last line in “myList”.)

I think I have to do something with

```
for x in myList
  if x[0..3] in vmList:
    do something
```

Or am I wrong?

edit:

This is the code I’m using now:

```
for app in myList:
  appName = app[0]
  vmType = app[3]
  numbervms = app[4]

  for x in range(0, numbervms):
    nodeName = vmList[i]
    nodeNameShort = nodeName.split(‘_’)[1]
    if nodeNameShort == vmType:
      do something
    else:
      i += 1
      nodeName = vmList[i]
      do something
```

This works, but in my example APP3 will be skipped. APP4 is going well again. APP5 is also skipped.

Update:

I'm using the code now based on what's supplied by @Tobs40.

```
for x in myList:
    ec = int(cls[4])
    logger('INFO', 'Node','ec is: %s' % (ec))
    ac = 0

    for y in vmList[0]:
        logger('INFO', 'Node','x: %s' % (cls[3][:3]))
        logger('INFO', 'Node','y: %s' % (y[:3]))
        if x[3][:3] == y[:3]:
            nodeName = y
            logger('INFO', 'Node','nodeName: %s' % (customNodeType))
            memberName = 'APP_%s_%s_%s_1' % (cls[0], clsType, nodeName.split('_')[1])
            createClusterAndMembers(clusterName, nodeName, memberName)
            ac += 1
            logger('INFO', 'Node','ac is: %s' % (ac))
    if ec != ac:
        logger('ERROR', 'Node','not enough available nodes')
    else:
        for  y in vmList[0]:
            if x[3][:3] == y[:3]:
                nodeName = y
                logger('INFO', 'Node','nodeName: %s' % (customNodeType))
                memberName = 'APP_%s_%s_%s_1' % (cls[0], clsType, nodeName.split('_')[1])
                createClusterAndMembers(clusterName, nodeName, memberName)
                ac += 1
                logger('INFO', 'Node','ac is: %s' % (ac))
```

It's looping correct now, however something is just not working right.
I've added some extra logging, and this is what I see :

```
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - customNodeType information: ABC
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - ec is: 1
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - cls: ABC
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - y: A
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - cls: ABC
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - y: B
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - cls: ABC
[08-07-2020 10:06:40]  INFO       Node - y: C
```

The content of vmList looks like this

```
[u'ABC_host1', u'XYZ_host2']
```

Update:

Changed this

```
for y in vmList[0]:
```

to this

```
for y in vmList:
```

And now it's working correct. Everything is created as desired.
Final question, the 'else' part, I've copied the for y in vmList loop, but was that what you meant by going through the list again?

Update :

Ok, stuck again. Everything works great when I need to deploy 1 app. It may be that there are 2 VMs, on which the same application must come. (then mylist [4] is eg 2).
Those VMs therefore start with the same name (eg ABC_host1, ABC_host2).

I don't think that will work with

```
for y in vmList
```

because then every VM will try to create something that can already exist on a previous VM.

Update:

Thanks @Tobs40, it's really getting better now.

This is the code I'm using now

```
count = {app[0]:int(app[4]) for app in myList}

for app in myList:
    appName = cls[0]
    appType = cls[1]
    settingLabel = cls[2]
    NodeType = cls[3]
    numberMembers = cls[4]

    clusterName = 'CLS_%s_%s' % (cls[0], clsType)
    
    for nodeName in vmList:
        if app[3][:3] == nodeName[:3]:
            if count[app[0]] <= 0:
                logger('INFO', 'Node','Already enough members on %s' % (nodeName))
            else:
                logger('INFO', 'Node','nodeName: %s' % (customNodeType))
                memberName = 'APP_%s_%s_%s_1' % (app[0], appType, nodeName.split('_')[1])
                createClusterAndMembers(clusterName, nodeName, memberName)
    if count[app[0]] > 0:
            logger('INFO', 'Node','Not enough nodes')
```

With vmList like this:

```
vmList = [[“AAA_hostname_1”, “BBB_hostname”, "AAA_hostname_2"]]
```

And myList like so:

```
clsConfig = [["QWE","O","v2.2","AAA", 1,],
          ["RTY","WS","v2.1","AAA", 1],
          ["ASD","O","v2.2","BBB", 1],
          ["FGH","T","v2.2","BBB", 1],
          ["FGH","WS","v2.2","BBB", 1],
          ["VBN","O","v2.5","AAA", 2]]
```

The different deployments are being done, however a deployment is now being done on each vm where there are two of them.
I think I should add a break statement somewhere in the if or else?

Update:

Ok got it, I've added a

```
count[app[0]] = count[app[0]] - 1
```

In the else branch.
But now I find out that I should actually count on app [0] and app [1] together. Because it is possible that there are two apps, with the same name in the 1st position, but another in the 2nd position.

How can I include this in the count?
`count = {app [0] [1]: int (app [4]) for app in cleanCLS}`
Does not give me the right result

Comment: Why `vmList` is a list of list ? You want to compare to 4th field from myList item ?

Comment: When asking a question of the type "how can I do ___ with this data?" you need to provide your expected output (and normally also the code you've got and the wrong output that it gives you)...

Comment: @gzeel please edit your question to add the extra information (comments don't format well).

Comment: @thebjorn done.

Comment: Now it's a much better question (I've upvoted).  Question: should it be `for i in range(...):` - you're using `i` inside the for loop...

Comment: Thank you, eeh.. I don’t think so? x has nothing to do with i. x can be 0,1 or 2 (usually, depending on the number given in myList). I’m using i for the position in vmList.
When numbervms is 1, there will be 1 matching entry in vmList. When numbervms is 2, there will be 2 vm’s in vmList where the app has to be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 3: The Question Owner has updated his post
# the owner wanted to have one application being assigned
# not only according to the first, but the combination of
# of the first and second entry
# just replace app[0] with tuple(a[:2])
# needs to be a tuple so the count-dictionary(=hashmap)
# can hash (can only hash immutable things obviously)

```
count = {tuple(a[:2]):int(app[4]) for app in myList}
# count["APP1"] = 2 ;-) It's called a dictionary

for app in myList:
    for vm in vmList:
        # = for all combinations of an application and a vm
        if app[3][:3] == vm[:3]:
            # this app should run on this vm
            if count[tuple(a[:2])] <= 0:
                # already assigned to enough vms
            else:
                # make this app run on this vm or whatever you want
            count[tuple(a[:2])] -= 1 # forgot this at first sorry
    if count[tuple(a[:2])] > 0:
        # app hasn't been assigned to enough vms

 #Btw. the second loop in the previous code (in the else part of
 #ec != ac) was just in case you want to do something for every y if 
 #everything went alright. You said you wanted an error if those two 
 #numbers are different but actually you wanted to have more or as many 
 #vm's and additionally(!) an error in case there aren't enough. I hope 
 #that this code will help you :)
```

Comment: Creating same string variable `y[:3]` many times is not very efficient. You create a list of prefixes like I did.

Comment: Your are approach is right. Actually question is not cleared about is want to compare all values in list or fourth element of element with vmList. Upvoting answer.

Comment: @Tobs40 Will try this one out. How would you pass in the numbervm’s in myList? Another for loop between the first two? When this is 1, there will be 1 matching vm in vmList. When this is 2, there should be 2 matching vm’s in vmList, otherwise it should raise an error.

Comment: Dear @gzeel, I think that you might save yourself a lot of headache by having a brief look at some basic Python tutorials!  :) But asking these things is ok of course. I have updated my answer and hope that it'll be useful to you. If not tell me again. Would you prefer a more elegant version of my code using 'advanced' Python concepts instead btw.? Once I understand what you want of course ;)

Comment: @Tobs40 Thanks, I've updated my original post with a new question and code. It's correct that I have basic Python knowledge. However I need to alter this code to make it work for a new situation, based on what someone has originally wrote. I'd like to learn. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your original post, so I'll reply here. As far as I understand, your problem is that you'd only like to assign it to one vm but the current code assigns an application to multiple vms? However I have the strong suspicion that I didn't quite understand what you wanted. Maybe expand a bit on the general purpose of the script and the problem it is supposed to solve

Comment: @gzeel Ok, I think I've got it know. You're just trying to figure out which application(s) to deploy on which vm. Possibly multiple applications to one vm or one application to multiple vms. Again I've updated my answer :)

Comment: @Tobs40 You're code is really helping. I used it, run into a little problem, something I don't understand yet. I updated the original post.

Answer (score -1):

Try this this search first three letter of vmList inside myList. '

Creating extra vmList3 for searching purpose using first three letter from list. Then scanning through myList.

```py
myList = [["APP1", "X", "v3", "AAB", "2"],
            ["APP2", "X", "v3", "AAA", "2"],
            ["APP3", "Z", "v3", "BBB", "2"],
            ["APP4", "Z", "v3", "BBB", "2"],
            ["APP5", "Z", "v3", "AAA", "2"]]
vmList = [["AAA_hostname", "BBB_hostname"]] 
vmList3 = [x[:3] for x in vmList[0]]
for x in myList:
  for y in vmList3:
      if y in x:
          print("found")
      else:
          print("not found")
```

Comment: Same mistake, `y[:3]` is computed many times. Your solution is not efficient. Make corrections buddy.

Comment: @ThunderPheonix you're being rude for no reason at all. This is a correct answer, whether it is efficient or not depends on the data - i.e. with the given data I don't think you could measure a difference (but you're welcome to add a performance comparison to your own answer if you feel strongly about it).

Comment: You are right made changes @ThunderPheonix Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @thebjorn I am not rude at all. I just commented his solution and I am right. Indeed, he just made changes. My solution inspired him. 
It is very simple: when you compute the same value many times, it means you can improve it by computing it once at the begining and store it in a variable.

Comment: If I were to guess, the downvote is because this is essentially a code-only answer...

Comment: @thebjorn how about mine?

Comment: @ThunderPheonix Firstly, I don't know why people downvote... maybe because your explanation is very dense and perhaps considered difficult to follow for what the downvoters perceive the level of this OP is? Maybe if you write "you have to do.." then show the code-line that does it, and the output, before moving onto the next step in your algorithm? (just a suggestion).  Writing a comment on someone else's answer saying that they "don't deserve" an upvote is not going to get you much goodwill (so fewer upvotes to balance the downvotes). You do you, of course, this is just my .05 EUR...

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
vmList3 = [x[:3] for x in vmList[0]]
for x in myList:
   try:
       index = vmList3.index(x[3])
       print("found", index, vmList[0][index])
   except :
       print("prefix not found in vmList")
```

You have to create a list of 3-chars-prefix VMs names `vmList3`. Then, go through `myList`, and for each element in it, take the fourth element `x[3]` and search it in `vmList`. If you don't get any exception, it means that the element exists in the list, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: @thebjorn where doyou see `catch`? Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: Even if existing of match your answer is not giving desired output. make correction.

Comment: @aviboy2006 I assumed that `vmList` is a simple list. It is more neat. Now it does give the desired answer.

Comment: @ThunderPheonix you know that we can see the changes you make right? (your first version had catch instead of except - as you can see, I removed my comment once you fixed that problem).  I have neither up or downvoted your answer.

Comment: Yeah I know. But I removed it, so it is not here anymore.

Comment: Neither is my comment. Refresh your page.

Comment: You approach is perfect but its not giving desired output even it string find. @ThunderPheonix

Comment: @aviboy2006 the desired output is not even specified in the question. How could you judge? `index` method gives me the index if it's exists then I get the whrome name of the VM.

Comment: you can see "AAA" from "AAA_hostname" is available in myList.. Expectation is result show index of it or something else.

Comment: @aviboy2006 This is what I did by doing `print("found", index, vmList[0][index])`.